# Multiple derivatives of same function evaluated in x0

Tags: python, sympy

I wanted to calculate the derivative of a function, and evaluating it at a point.
So for example, I have the function `f(x)=x^5+2*x^3`:

I have tried this

```
def diff(f, x0, N):
    x = symbols('x')
    for i in range(1, N+1):
       print(diff(f(x), x, i).subs(x, x0)
```

But I want to use the previous derivative to calculate the next one, so it uses less time to compute. Any idea how to do that? I've tried to do this:

```
def deri(fkt,x0,n):
   x = symbols('x')
   f = fkt
   for i in range(1, n+1):
       f = diff(f(x), x, 1)
       print(f(x0))
   return
```

But it gives me the error: `'Add' object is not callable.`

I get the same error using this code:

```
def deri(f, x0, N):
    w = symbols('w')
    A = np.zeros(N+1)
    A[0] = f(x0)
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        f = diff(f(w), w)
        A[i] = f.subs(w, x0)
    return(A)
```

Any way to use the previous derivative of a function to compute the next?

Bonus question: If the function inputted is defined as

```
def h(y):
   return(y**5+2*(y**2)).
```

It is a function of y, how to I make my program able to take the derivative of any single variable function no matter what the variable is?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a complete stand-alone example.  So, it is unclear how you defined your function variables nor how you are calling `deri`. Also, note that calling your function `def diff(....):`, you are shadowing the sympy `diff` function, leading to surprising recursive calls.

You also shouldn't create a new symbolic `x` variable inside `deri()`. The function `f` was defined earlier using another `x`.

Normally, in sympy, you write your function as an expression, without using brackets.  E.g. `f=x**5+2*x**3` and then `print(diff(f, x, i).subs(x, x0))`. Instead of `f(x0)` one writes `f.subs(x, x0)`..

A stand-alone example could look like:

```py
from sympy import diff, symbols

def deri(fkt, x0, n):
    f = fkt
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        f = diff(f, x, 1)
        print(f'The {i}th derivative is "{f}" with value {f.subs(x, x0)} at x={x0}')
    return

x = symbols('x')
f = x ** 5 + 2 * x ** 3
deri(f, 1, 5)
```

```
The 1th derivative is "5*x**4 + 6*x**2" with value 11 at x=1
The 2th derivative is "20*x**3 + 12*x" with value 32 at x=1
The 3th derivative is "60*x**2 + 12" with value 72 at x=1
The 4th derivative is "120*x" with value 120 at x=1
The 5th derivative is "120" with value 120 at x=1
```